# Nested liquid loop in Jekyll does not iterate multiple sub-items corrently

Tags: for-loop, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I have a .yml-file that contains companies. Each company have sub-items, and each sub-item also have tags. It looks like this:

**YAML**

```
- name: acme
  subfolderitems:
    - item: books
      item-url: http://acme.com/books
      item-tag:
        - Nice book
        - Cool books
        - Wow books
```

I want to display the company names in a table on each row, together with the tags. Right now I am using this solution:

**Code**

```
<table>
{% for company in site.data.companies %}
{% for subfolderitem in company.subfolderitems %}
{% if subfolderitem.item == page.ref %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
        <td>{% for subfolderitem in company.subfolderitems %}<span class="tag">{{ subfolderitem.item-tag }}</span>{% endfor %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

**Frontmatter** (for books)

```
---
layout: page
ref: books
title: Books
---
```

My problem is that the loop for the tags is not working as intended.

**Output**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>acme</td>
      <td><span class="tag">Nice bookCool booksWow books</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Desired output should instead be this `<span class="tag">Nice book</span><span class="tag">Cool books</span><span class="tag">Wow books</span>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `inspect` filter :

```
<span class="tag">{{ subfolderitem.item-tag | inspect }}</span>
```

You can see that the tags array is printed in one time.
You need to add another loop to print tags one by one.

```
<table>
{% for company in site.data.companies %}
{% for subfolderitem in company.subfolderitems %}
{% if subfolderitem.item == page.ref %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
    <td>{% for subfolderitem in company.subfolderitems %}
        {% for tag in subfolderitem.item-tag %}
        <span class="tag">{{ tag }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}</td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly and I learned something new. Thank you! Since my database contains I added more than one subfolderitems per company, I added `{% if subfolderitem.item == page.ref %}` before `{% for tag in subfolderitem.item-tag %}` so the correct tags are displayed on each page.